# Icon click to draw rectangle on canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is supposed to be a very straightforward task in HTML and JavaScript. I have an icon bar, at the moment with a single clickable link, New Box. Below the icon bar, I have a canvas. My goal is to draw a new rectangle on the canvas every time the user presses the New Box button.

Right now, my icon bar and canvas appear correctly and I can click on the New Box link of the icon bar but no rectangle appears on the canvas, even though I have specified its `onclick` parameter as: `newBox`.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

function newBox(e) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "#ADD8E6";
  context.fillRect(50, 50, 150, 150);
  context.fill();
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: ivory;
  padding:20px;
}

.icon-bar {
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: #555; 
  overflow: auto; 
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.icon-bar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 11.11%;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000; 
}

.icon-bar-text {
  font-style: normal;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50; 
}

#canvas {
  width:95%;
  height:30%;
  border:4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Builder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="icon-bar">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon-bar-text" onclick="newBox();" title="Click to add a new box on canvas">New Box
          </i>
        </a>
       <!-- ...there will be more <a> tags here -->
    </div>

    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like it's working after my edit. Can you confirm that? @lazarea

Comment: Your code is fine, it draws a new rectangle when user clicks. But, it draws it same position (50,50), you must give a new postion to your rectangle if you want add more than 1

Comment: It does indeed! I'm trying to find what you modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store and update the `y` position as shown below. Note that you'll also need to increase the canvas size in case boxes go out of view.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

let prevY = 0;

function newBox(e) {
  context.fillStyle = "#ADD8E6";
  context.fillRect(50, prevY, 150, 150);
  prevY+= 160; // height + some padding
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
  padding: 20px;
}

.icon-bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.icon-bar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 11.11%;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.icon-bar-text {
  font-style: normal;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#"><i class="icon-bar-text" onclick="newBox();" title="Click to add a new box on canvas">New Box</i></a>
  <!-- ...there will be more <a> tags here -->
</div>

<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Very strange, I see that it works here on SO but the rectangle just doesn't appear when I run the code from Atom.